# How to maintain a reference to a tableview cell?

Tags: swift, uitableview

I've built a basic media player app.
I have a tableView in which I list Podcasts.
Within the row item, I list the podcast title.
I also use the detailTextLabel to list a countdown of the current playtime.

Everything works fine except when I scroll the tableView the cell gets reloaded and I can no longer update the time.

How can I keep a reference to the cell so I can update the cell text even after scrolling?

Here are the pertinent pieces of code....

```
var myCell = UITableViewCell()

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell:UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "cell")

    .... cell code

    return cell
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    myMP.nowPlayingItem = qryPodcasts.items![indexPath.row]
    if myMP.playbackState != MPMusicPlaybackState.Playing {
       myMP.play()
    }

    // Grab a reference to the selected item
    // for displaying elapsed time
    myCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)!
}

func startTimer(){
    myTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: #selector(View_Podcast_List.updateTimer), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}
func stoptimer(){
    myTimer.invalidate()
}
func updateTimer(){
    let nowPlayingItemDuration =  myMP.nowPlayingItem?.valueForProperty(MPMediaItemPropertyPlaybackDuration) as! Double
    let remainingTime = nowPlayingItemDuration - myMP.currentPlaybackTime ;

    myCell.detailTextLabel?.text = CommonFuncs.secondsToTime(Int(remainingTime))
}
```

Comment: One solution could be keep a list with the state of every cell, you can't keep a reference to the cell because it's reused automatically. In this way every time the cell is reused the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` it's called and you can restore the state of the cell and restore your `NSTimer`, etc

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are 2 ways you can proceed on this:
1st one is tag approach:
In your cellForRow give tag to cell:

```
MyCell.tag = indexPath.row
```

When you select an item in didSelect store the indexPath.row in a property.
Now in updateTimer method extract the cell using viewWithTag(indexPath.row) which will give you your cell and then update the timer on that cell.

2nd Approach:
In didSelect store the indexPath.row in property when selected. Then in cellForRow if indexPath.row is equal to the select property from didSelect then call the method updateTimer which actually returns the text (you may need to update your method in this case)

```
if(indexPath.row == selectRow) {
    myCell.detailTextLabel?.text = self.updateTimer()
}
```

Comment: Arun - I chose the tag method and only had to make one change to your suggestion. instead of "indexPath.row" I used "indexPath".   var selectedRow = NSIndexPath()  THEN in cellForRow: cell.tag = indexPath.row  THEN in didSelect:  selectedRow = indexPath  THEN  in updateTimer: let myCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(selectedRow)

Comment: Yes you can change the implementation according to your need. I just gave the basic flow how to achieve it.

Comment: Using tags is awful but giving tags to cells is really really bad. The easiest solution would be to use use a static cell - just create an instance of the cell and always return it for the given index - and never reuse it.

Comment: @Sulthan - How do I create Static Cells? Can you point me to a Swift sample?

Answer (score 1):

You can call cellForRowAtIndexPath in the timer callback itself. You then have two possibilities: cellForRowAtIndexPath returns nil, so it is not on the screen, so there is nothing to do. Or it returns not nil, then you update it.

Make sure in the cellForRowAtIndexPath delegate method to set the right time in case you missed a few updates when the row was not on the screen.

Trying to hold a reference to the cell isn't going to work. It prevents the cell from being deallocated, but it doesn't prevent it from being reused for a different cell.

Comment: I'm actually using the second method as tags did not work well. So I do as you suggest - cellForRowAtIndexPath within the timer update and check for nil...

Answer (score 0):

```
weak var myCell: UITableViewCell?

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell:UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "cell")

    .... cell code

    if tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow == indexPath {
        myCell = cell;
    }

    return cell
}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    myMP.nowPlayingItem = qryPodcasts.items![indexPath.row]
    if myMP.playbackState != MPMusicPlaybackState.Playing {
       myMP.play()
    }

    // Grab a reference to the selected item
    // for displaying elapsed time
    myCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)!
}

func startTimer(){
    myTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: #selector(View_Podcast_List.updateTimer), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}
func stoptimer(){
    myTimer.invalidate()
}

func updateTimer(){
    guard myCell != nil else { return }
    let nowPlayingItemDuration =  myMP.nowPlayingItem?.valueForProperty(MPMediaItemPropertyPlaybackDuration) as! Double
    let remainingTime = nowPlayingItemDuration - myMP.currentPlaybackTime ;

    myCell?.detailTextLabel?.text = CommonFuncs.secondsToTime(Int(remainingTime))
}
```